# Regular Expression Dot not working

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

So I'm trying to parse through a file and I have the following code:

```
def learn_re(s):
pattern=re.compile("[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3} .")
if pattern.match(s):
    return True
return False
```

This matches with "01:01:01.123 —"; however, when I add in one more character, it fails to work. For example if I edit my code so that it's

```
def learn_re(s):
pattern=re.compile("[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3} . C")
if pattern.match(s):
    return True
return False
```

This fails to match with "01:01:01.123 — C" What's happening here?

Comment: `.` in regular expressions mean any character. To match a `.` use `\.` in your regular expression.

Comment: @ShriroopJoshi: but if it matches *any* character, then logically it should also match a single full stop.

Comment: On this example, escaping first dot doesn't solve anything.

Comment: @revo yes, but it's still bad form and highlights the need for the `r` prefix on the string.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue - the second example works fine.

Comment: The "This fails to match" string contains an extended character in your post: the em-dash. Is that one character, according to your locale, or is it perceived as more than 1? (I.e., UTF-8.)

Comment: Hi, so I edited my code to put the r prefix in front of the string and I tried putting a \ before every dot, but the issue still remains

Comment: @RadLexus Hi, I figured it out with your help. It turns out that the long dash is considered to be 3 characters long?

Comment: I was about to say "I think the em dash is unicode". Let me update my answer.

Comment: Three separate characters [sounds about right](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014/index.htm). Your Python build is not Unicode aware. You may want to [edit] your post and add what version you are using.

Comment: Yes I got it later. @JimmyKim so you mean this `[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3} ... C` matches the second?

Comment: Yup although instead of doing ... I just did .{3}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that your — is a unicode character. When in a `str`, it actually behaves more like several characters:

```
>>> print len('—')
3
```

But, if you use a `unicode` instead of a `str`:

```
>>> print len(u'—')
1
```

And so, the following will print `True`:

```
def learn_re(s):
    pattern=re.compile("[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3} . C")
    if pattern.match(s):
        return True
    return False

print learn_re(u"01:01:01.123 — C")
```

Note that this behavior is specific to python 2. In python 3, `str` and `unicode` are merged into a single `str` type, and so this distinction is not required.

Answer (score 1):

Rhe em dash in your string is a unicode character, which will be interpreted as multiple characters [(3 in your case)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014/index.htm). Your version of python is not unicode-aware so you'll either need to match 3 characters to capture `.{3}` the dash, match the character exactly in your expression, or use a different version of python.

A few notes regarding your expression; You should always prefix your regular expression strings with `r'...'` so that your `\` escapes will be interpreted correctly.

A `.` in a regular expression has a special meaning, it will match any single character. If you need a period/decimal point, you need to escape the dot `\.`.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3} .')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, but I'm aware that . will match any single character. I'm using it to deal with the long dash. However, shouldn't my edited code still match with the "01:01:01.123 — C"?

Comment: This answer really doesn't provide a solution to this question.

Comment: The problem isn't that an expression intended to only match a literal `.` is also matching other characters - it's the opposite. An expression that should match is not doing so... or so the OP says. It works fine for me.

Comment: The "finally" portion of this answer is the actual answer. The rest is actively _un_helpful and misleading. If a regex is too restrictive, making it more restrictive isn't going to help, and had nothing to do with the actual issue in this case. Please read questions more carefully before answering.

Comment: I'll change the order. I'd like to keep those details in there because they're important to the original question's code.

Comment: They're not important at all. OP wasn't trying to match only a literal `.` there. If you just look at the question, you will quickly see that OP was trying to match a character that _wasn't_ a literal `.`, which means that the unescaped `.` was what they needed. It wasn't working because of Unicode encoding. Nothing to do with `\.` in the slightest.

Comment: It's in reference to the `.` that's matching a decimal place earlier in the expression, not the one for the em dash. While it's technically valid, it's obviously supposed to be a literal, not a wildcard.